# Find and replace a word in a file, how to avoid reading the entire file into a buffer?

Tags: c

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to write to a file, then perform a find and replace on it, with the condition that the old word must have the same length as the new one.

What I'm currently doing is finding the file size, then allocating a memory of that size and assign it to a buffer, read the entire file into the buffer, change the words, then write it back on the file.

This would fail if the files are too big, the only thing I can think of to avoid this is:

1. Check if the buffer contains `\n`
2. If it doesn't (the entire line wasn't read), then use `realloc` to increase its size by any amount (the original for example)
3. Delete the last `n` characters in the buffer, where `n` is the length of the word we want to replace. (To avoid reading the same data again)
4. Set the file pointer back by `n`. (Because the word could be cut)

Is there any other method? This feels complicated, and realloc causes some issues that might make the program need new buffers.

This is the current code where I read the entire file at once:

```
void replace_word(const char *s, const char *old_word, const char *new_word){
    FILE *original_file;

    if((original_file = fopen(s, "r+")) == NULL){
        perror(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const int BUFFER_SIZE = fsize(s);
    char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    char *init_loc = buffer;

    int word_len = strlen(old_word);
    int word_frequency = 0;

    fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, original_file);

    while((buffer = strstr(buffer, old_word))){
            memcpy(buffer, new_word, word_len);
            word_frequency++;
        }

    buffer = init_loc;
    rewind(original_file);
    fputs(buffer, original_file);

    printf("'%s' found %i times\n", old_word, word_frequency);

    fclose(original_file);

    free(buffer);

}
```

Comment: If you write it back to a *different* file, you won't have to read the entire file first, you can process it line by line.

Comment: @WeatherVane And if a line is too big for the buffer?

Comment: Then do as you suggest and `realloc` when there is no trailing `newline` (and not EOF).

Comment: Text files containing variable-length data (like most text files) are notoriously hard to modify "in place". If the word you write is to short part of the old word will be visible, and if it's to long then you will overwrite the existing text that you should not modify.

Comment: @WeatherVane Like I said, I don't want to realloc, it's going to get complicated if I do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Like I said, the words must have the same length, I do that check in `main`.

Comment: In that case if the word length to be changed is length `n` then use a circular buffer of length `n` and read 1 char at a time into this buffer and if the characters in the buffer match the target then replace them and write the whole buffer to the new file if not just write the oldest character and when the input reaches EOF write out any remaining characters in the buffer. Warning: don't make any comparisons unless the buffer is full. You will also learn how to use a circular buffer ;) P.S. you could also use a linear buffer and copy it down every time you write characters out of it.

Comment: @MichaelX *And if a line is too big for the buffer?*  Use [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/functions/getdelim.html).

Comment: You may implement a form of KMP algorithm to find the instances of the word, go back the length of the word and overwrite it with the replacement (it only works because the original word and the new one are the same length). This requires no buffers (although for performance the C standard library and the operating system *will* have internal buffers)

Comment: @AndrewHenle - yes, you can use `getline`, but why? You don't care if the line is too big for the buffer... all you care about is reading buffer sized chunks at a time, and then backing up x-chars to the last word-delimiter (whitespace?) and then starting your next read at the `current + bufsize - x + 1` location and repeating until you hit `EOF`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin *yes, you can use `getline`, but why?*  You said it yourself. Here's why: *You don't care if the line is too big for the buffer... all you care about is reading buffer sized chunks at a time, and then backing up x-chars to the last word-delimiter (whitespace?) and then starting your next read at the current + bufsize - x + 1 location and repeating until you hit EOF.*  All that is replaced by a single `getline()` call.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying `getline` is wrong, but regardless of which read method you use, (whether `fgetc` or `getline`) you are reading (up to) 8192-byte chunks from disk. With `getline`, you get a default 120-byte buffer that is `realloc`'ed, as required, to hold the entire line. If that's what you want, that's fine. I would rather avoid the overhead of the dynamic allocation altogether for a word search and just use a sliding-window over the default read buffer. Whatever works for you.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I used your getline() suggestion, since it's much easier. But can't a line theoretically hold a huge number of characters that could cause the buffer to overflow and crash? Or is there a fixed number of characters in each line defined in C?

Comment: @MichaelX *But can't a line theoretically hold a huge number of characters that could cause the buffer to overflow and crash?*  Yes, it can.  But you can check the size of the file easily enough to ensure it's not too big since any line can't be larger than the file it's in.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a "sliding window" algorithm using just one fixed buffer of any length that you want, as long as the buffer is longer than the word you are looking for. 
The pseudocode to search for a word of length N would look as follows:

- Begin with a buffer full of data from the file.
- Loop:

  - Search for the word in the buffer; if found:

    - calculate the offset of the word in the file
    - write the replacement over it.
  - move the last N - 1 characters from the end of the buffer to the beginning of the buffer.  (That's because these characters may contain part of the word, and the remaining part may be in the beginning of the next buffer that you will read.)
  - fill the remainder of the buffer from the file.
  - repeat the above loop until you reach the end of the file.

For this to perform well, the buffer must be much longer than the word.  So, if your word is up to 100 characters long, the buffer should be at least 4 kilobytes long.  But 64 and even 128 kilobyte buffers work well in modern systems.

Do not forget to seek to the right offset before each read operation.

Comment: I feel that I understood this wrong. I assume you'd need a secondary file to write the buffer to each time, correct? And I assume you do that operation after the "write the replacement over it" step.
Wouldn't this result in the same data getting written on the secondary file more than once? Unless you delete the last N-1 characters from the secondary file, or move the pointer.

Comment: No, you do not need a second file. You just overwrite the word in the output file.  Seek at the offset of the word, and write `strlen(word)` characters.  (That is, not an entire buffer.)  You can do it because of the condition that the old word must have the same length as the new one.

Comment: Oh, I kinda get it now. A few more questions, the offset of the word inside the file in the first read is the same as its offset inside the buffer, relative to the beginning. Correct? For the second read, it's the size of the buffer, plus its current offset in the buffer. Is that right?

Comment: The calculation for the file offset of the word is a bit involved.  It is the file offset at which the current buffer was read, plus the offset of the word within the buffer, minus the number of characters you moved from the end of the buffer to the beginning of the buffer in the previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution or not, but i would just look at one word at a time. Then when you find the word you want to change, go back by the size of the word you read and overwrite it. As long as the word is the same size, it should work.

Use `fgetc` to get one char at a time from your file. Replace `getchar` with `fgetc` in the code below.

Just modify this code, to work with `fgetc`, it from K&R famous book on C, which i read 10 months ago, to learn C. I've used it a few times in my own code, and it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* getword: get next word or character from input */
int getword(char *word, int lim)
{
    int c, getch(void);
    void ungetch(int);
    char *w = word;

    while (isspace(c = getch()))
        ;
    if (c != EOF)
        *w++ = c;
    if (!isalpha(c)) {
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    }
    for ( ; --lim > 0; w++)
        if (!isalnum(*w = getch())) {
            ungetch(*w);
            break;
        }
    *w = '\0';
    return word[0];
}

#define BUFSIZE 100
char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* buffer for ungetch */
int bufp = 0;      /* next free position in buf */

int getch(void) /* get a (possibly pushed-back) character */
{
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar(); //change to fgetc  
}

void ungetch(int c)    /* push character back on input */
{
    if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
        printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}
```

You can make the max size of the array anything you want, it's set to 100, since there should be no words bigger then 100 char, but you can make it anything.

just modify the code to read form fgetc, and end when you hit EOF.